# How do I remove a clickable link from asp:Gridview column?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to remove a clickable link from asp:Gridview column when some condition is true.

I tried this:

```
Gridview.attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

But the hyperlink is still clickable. I don't want clickable hyperlinks when the grid is disabled. How can I do it in C#.net?

Comment: Where is that "clickable link" and what is it(Hyperlink,LinkButton,HyperLinkField, html-anchor,...)?

Comment: You can also wrap it around panel control & disable the whole based based on some condition

Comment: "<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address Type" HeaderStyle-Width="90px" ItemStyle-Width="90px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="CompanyTypeText">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <a href="#" id="lnkEditCompany" title="Edit Company" onclick="return EditAddress('<%# Eval("AddressId") %>')">
<%# Eval("AddressTypeText")%> </a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>"

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a", $("#<%=Gridview.ClientID%>")).each(function(index){
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set columns using index.

```
if (someCond) 
{ 
  ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[0]).DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"; 
  ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).DataFormatString = "{0:f2}"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `Item_Databound` event & write code inside it to check for the condition then you can easily disable enable any server side control etc..